# NSUserDefaults don't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

My app consists of the following:

1. Main data view controls
2. Settings view controller (that has 3 text fields for settings)

In (2).m when keys are pressed down, the following code is used:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if(textField==_serverAddress){

        NSLog(@"new server adress %@", textField.text);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:@"serverAddress"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    if(textField==_login){
        NSLog(@"new login %@", textField.text );
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:@"login"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    if(textField==_password)
{
        NSLog(@"new password %@", textField.text);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:@"password"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

In viewDidLoad, the following code is used:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    // Get the stored data before the view loads

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *savedServerAddress = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedServerAddress"];
    NSString *savedLogin = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedLogin"];
    NSString *savedPassword = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedPassword"];

    // Update the UI elements with the saved data
    self.serverAddress.text = savedServerAddress;
    self.login.text = savedLogin;
    self.password.text = savedPassword;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _serverAddress.delegate = self;
    _login.delegate = self;
    _password.delegate = self;

}
```

When I change the settings to new ones in (2) and then go back to (1) and then go back to (2) I see plain text fields, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have *different keys* for storing and reading the user defaults. For example, the server address is stored with the key `@"serverAddress"`, but read with the key `@"savedServerAddress"`.

You have to use the same keys, otherwise reading the user defaults will always return `nil`.

Comment: I think Martin R is right. Tip: One should always use a constant string or define a string literal to avoid these kind of bugs.

Comment: SNX!
hmmm.... Sorry, hurried to the code. Posted really typo. But it helped me to understand that the key names in NSUserDefaults must match the name of the field on the ViewController ...

Comment: @СебульбаКасторский: If an answer helped to solve the problem, you can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark. If it still does not work then let use know how we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `[super viewDidLoad];` should be the first statement in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: @(cyrillic characters): because it does the setup of the superclass. You're just lucky because you have a direct subclass of `UIViewController` which apparently does nothing, but in a deeper descendant, this could cancel out the set properties of your class, again resulting in empty labels (for example).